# Drupal - Tokens for Webform Component Values

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Is there a way to set up a Webform such that I can turn component field submissions into tokens for use in the submission email?

For example, I want to include "Message from [email address]" in the email subject line. The default options only allow for including only the component field in the email (subject: [email]), or only custom text.

Is there a way I can turn the component field submission into a token for use in the email? Looks like there's a module for turning webform items into tokens, but it's not for use within webform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - use `%value[key]` whenever you want to get a submitted field value. I found it from a random search that brought me here: http://drupal.org/node/1010648. 
Feels like `%value[key]` should be in the Token help dictionary in the email section of the webform admin UI this was a botch to find.

Comment: For Drupal 7, as of the current Webform module, this is on the module description under Webform > Emails > "Edit email settings" > "token values".